# How to check the python socket recvfrom() data

Tags: python, sockets, recv, recvfrom

I am working on socket programming in python. Using ESP python i have created a socket to server and sending a request (in API packet format, according to server code it will respond). In receiving socket, i need to check the data(if data is received, it need continue to next operation. If not, i need to send request once again). 
sending is okay. In receiving socket, if it is not receiving data, it is not going to next instruction.. please help me out.

code:

```
try:

    s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM)
    print "socket created"

except socket.error:

    print "failed to create socket"
    sys.exit()
```

sending data:

```
s.sendto("packet of data", 0, (HOST,PORT))
```

In receiving:

```
recvpack, payload=s.recvfrom(1024)

if not recvpack:

    s.sendto("packet of data", 0, (HOST,PORT))

elif(recvpack[]="packet of data"):

    pass # continue to next operations..
```

In the above receiving statement, if `recvfrom()` in not getting anydata, how to check `recvpack` and get back to next operations.. If `socket.settimeout()` or `socket.setblocking()` is the solution, how to use these..

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind a blocking call, I usually use settimeout to wait for a message. settimeout will raise an exception if it doesn't receive a message in time.

So basically you could do something like this:

```
s.settimeout(1)
try:
    recvpack, payload = s.recvfrom(1024)
except error:
    recvpack = None
if recvpack is not None:
    ...
```

Source : https://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html#socket.socket.settimeout